# How do I target a specific element nested in HTML/CSS code?

Tags: html, css

I want to target a specific element and whatever properties I set on the logo overrides the other listed items. For example, I have a border style that is solid and it runs through all the listed items of #nav. I just want to make the image link **logo** an exception to this. The logo is located right in the middle between portfolio and projects. How do I do this?

```
<!--NAVIGATION-->
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/jp-logo.png" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="classlist.html">Class List</a></li> <!--change URL later-->
    </ul>

#nav{
list-style-type: none; /*gets rid of bullets*/
padding: 0;
border-color: #FFB405;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px 0;
text-align:center;
}
#nav li{
display: inline; /*display list horizontally*/
}
#nav a{
display: inline-block; /*don't break onto new lines and follow padding accordingly*/
padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: How about using the .link ???

Comment: you have a border for the complete list and you want to remove the border from the logo?

Comment: sorry if I haven't understood your question, but can't you just style like `#logo > a {border: none;}`?

Comment: Do you want something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/exnxq/1/

Comment: yes thats what i mean.

Comment: I have added the answer btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the problem is more about removing the border from the logo than targeting the element since it has an id, thus targeting is as easy as `#logo`.

The first thing you need to do in order to exclude the logo from the border is apply the property to the list-items instead of the container `<ul>` then you just override the style in a following rule:

```
#nav li{
    display: inline-block; /*display list horizontally*/
    border-color: #FFB405;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0;
}

#nav #logo{
    border: 0;
}
```

Finally, if you go and apply this styles you'll notice a gap in between your list items, this is caused by the `display:inline-block` property and the whitespace in the HTML markup, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078297/2049063) for multiple ways to properly handle that.

Here's a complete demo of the solution in **[jsFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/VGjDt/)**

Answer (score 1):

Check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exnxq/2/)**

Give `border-top` and `border-bottom` to you `li` and target your `#logo` with `border:none;` this will solve your problem. 
And for the gap you can see in between `li` elements this can be solved by setting the parent elements `font-size:0;` and then define the `font-size:npx` to your `li` element.

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="classlist.html">Class List</a></li> <!--change URL later-->
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
ul#nav {
    margin:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    /*gets rid of bullets*/
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 0;
}
#nav li {
    margin:0;
    display: inline;
    /*display list horizontally*/
}
#nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    /*don't break onto new lines and follow padding accordingly*/
    padding:10px;
    border-top:1px solid #FFB405;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFB405;
    margin:0;
    font-size: 16px;
}
ul#nav li#logo a {
    border-top:none;
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

Comment: you should add an explanation of the changes you made, also I wouldn't use negative margin to fight the space between the blocks

Comment: `font-size:0` is not advisable either, if one is able to change the HTML markup then removing the whitespce at the source is preferable

Comment: @koala_dev i think it would be good to have font-size:0 , rather than adding html comments in between all the listed list items.

Comment: It's definitely not a good practice, Safari 5 and Android have problems with it but most importantly it breaks any subsequent layout based on `ems` and `%`, I suggest you read the link I posted in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
#nav > #logo a
```

This matches with an element with id logo, tag `<a>` and children of element with id nav

Or even

```
#logo a
```

is enough.